# How to capture status on bash for shell script out result

Tags: shell

I need to capture the Complete status from my *testSatus.sh* shell and perform next action from command line.

Example:

I have my *testSatus.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Hello'
if [[ $1 == '1' ]]; then
  echo 'Status: In Progress....'
elif [[ $1 == '2' ]]; then
   echo 'Status: Complete...'
else
   echo 'Status: Failure...'
fi
```

which is called from

```
#!/bin/bash
sh testSatus.sh 

SUB='Complete'
if [[ "$STR" == *"$SUB"* ]]; then
  echo "do something. like update the build version."
fi
```

I need to capture the Complete status from my *testSatus.sh* shell and perform next action.

Comment: Well come to SO. Please read the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) on how to format your code and provide better formatted questions :)

Comment: @ParitoshShukla: The way you formatted your question, it is unclear what you want to know. Also define what you mean by the word _status_. In the context of shell programming, it is usually understood as the exit-code of a program.

Comment: Do you need the output od testStatus.sh or do you the exit status of test.Status.sh?

Answer (score 0):

```
 #!/bin/bash
 sh testSatus.sh
 status=$?

 if [[ $status -eq 0 ]]
 then
    SUB='Complete'
    if [[ "$STR" == *"$SUB"* ]]; then
        echo "do something. like update the build version."
    fi
 else
    echo "Other action"
 fi
```